# Laravel 5 assigning middleware to all sub urls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am using middleware to check for admin when trying to access the admin by page by redirecting to 'auth/login'

```
Route::get('admin', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
    'middleware' => 'admin'
]);
```

However I have some more pages within admin that will also require the same middleware...

e.g.

```
Route::get('admin/profiles', [ 
        'middleware' => 'admin', 
        'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index'
]);


Route::get('admin/pages', [ 
    'middleware' => 'admin', 
    'uses' => 'PageController@index'
]);
```

There are going to be many more too. Is there a way I can target all links within the `admin` url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('profiles', 'ProfilesController@index');
    Route::get('pages', 'PageController@index');
});
```

Read more about route groups: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups